# Cannot see usysribbons table in access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

For some reason my usysribbons table is not showing.  I have system tables showing and see a whole lot of system tables starting with "m" but none of the ones starting with "u".  Anyone know why those would still be hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table USysRibbons is not preset. You have to build it on your own.

Here is the standard tutorial from Microsoft:
https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Customize-the-Ribbon-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de

In your case, you should start at the headline
*Create and apply a custom Ribbon* 
and subheadline 
*Create the USysRibbons system table*